# Calling R function from Javascript (Node)

Tags: javascript, r, node.js, statistics

I'm trying to call a function from R script. I'm using [r-script](https://www.npmjs.com/package/r-script) like bellow :

```
var R = require("r-script");
var out = R('SampleR.R').data(5, 20).callSync();
console.log(out);
```

It returns undefined for R('SampleR.R'). Here is my R script, it's very simple script, just for testing.

```
print('Hello')
```

Please bear with me, I'm new to R script and javascript integration. What am I doing wrong here?

I also tried [js-call-r](https://github.com/codejie/js-call-r) , but no luck so far!

Comment: I don't know. Here are [two ways to call R in Node](https://github.com/stla/CallingRinNode), but they use different libraries.

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent Thanks, it didn't work unfortunately, but the good news is that I found the solution. I posted as the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally found the solution for my problem. Actually r-script or js-call-r didn't help me calling R function. Here is what I did:

I used [plumber package](https://www.rplumber.io/docs/) on R, so it creates a localhost so I could call my R functions via http request. Full documentation is on their website but here are the steps I took to set it up:

a- Open R Gui (64bit) Note: if you don't have R, go download it from: [cran.r-project.org/mirrors.html](http://cran.r-project.org/mirrors.html)

b- If you don't have plumber package, install it with R GUI with command: `install.packages("plumber")`

c- To check if R Gui root directory is at the file you want, send command: `getwd()`

d- If it's not the path you want, change it with: `setwd("C:/your/Desired/Path")`

e- Copy your R file into the same directory that you set in previous step

f- Send this command to start reading your R file: `pr <- plumber::plumb("YourRFile.R")`

g- run this command so it will run the local host: `pr$run()`

h- it should give you the port number so you can send receive messages